# Search Filter adapter not working properly

Tags: android, listview, filter

I am new to android and try to make a contact application with search on top of my *listview*. When I search for a contact it filters correct and shows me only the contact that I searched but when I try to *edit/delete* that contact it throws me **database/CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException** and also the *textview* that I use as phone hyperling does not work too...when I do not search at all everything works correct(edit, delete, phone call from text view etc.).I am posting the class with the search filter if you need more code let me know.I assume the adapter does not show the correct *listview* or something like that.
Sorry for big post thanks in advance.

```
public class Promitheutis extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
Button add_btn;
ListView Contact_listview;
ArrayList<Contact> contact_data = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Contact_Adapter cAdapter;
DatabaseHandler db;
String Toast_msg;
SearchView search_view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
try {
    Contact_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    Contact_listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    add_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    search_view = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    Set_Referash_Data();

    search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(this);


} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("some error", "" + e);
}
add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent add_user = new Intent(Promitheutis.this,
        Add_Update_User.class);
    add_user.putExtra("called", "add");
    add_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(add_user);
    finish();
    }
});

}





public void Set_Referash_Data() {
contact_data.clear();
db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
ArrayList<Contact> contact_array_from_db = db.Get_Contacts();

for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

    int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
    //String name = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
    String epitheto = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getEpitheto();
    String mobile = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getPhoneNumber();
    // String email = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getEmail();
    String eidos = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getEidos();
    Contact cnt = new Contact();
    cnt.setID(tidno);
    //cnt.setName(name);
    cnt.setEpitheto(epitheto);
    //cnt.setEmail(email);
    cnt.setEidos(eidos);
    cnt.setPhoneNumber(mobile);

    contact_data.add(cnt);
}
db.close();
cAdapter = new Contact_Adapter(Promitheutis.this, R.layout.listview_row,
    contact_data);
Contact_listview.setAdapter(cAdapter);
cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void Show_Toast(String msg) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onResume();
Set_Referash_Data();

}

public class Contact_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> implements Filterable {

ValueFilter valueFilter;    
Context context;
Activity activity;
int layoutResourceId;
Contact user;
ArrayList<Contact> data;
ArrayList<Contact> filterdata;

public Contact_Adapter(Activity act, int layoutResourceId,
    ArrayList<Contact> data) {
    super(act, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.activity = act;
    this.data = data;
    filterdata = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}



@Override
public Contact getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.get(position);
}



@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    holder = new UserHolder();
    //holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_epitheto_txt);
    holder.epitheto = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_epitheto_txt);
    //holder.email = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_email_txt);
    holder.eidos = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_eidos_txt);
    holder.number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_mobile_txt);
    holder.edit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
    holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
    holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    user = data.get(position);
    holder.edit.setTag(user.getID());
    holder.delete.setTag(user.getID());
    //holder.name.setText(user.getName());
    holder.epitheto.setText(user.getEpitheto());
    //holder.email.setText(user.getEmail());
    holder.eidos.setText(user.getEidos());
    holder.number.setText(user.getPhoneNumber());



   // String url = holder.number.getText().toString();
   //final Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));

    final String phone_no= holder.number.getText().toString().replaceAll("-", "");


    holder.number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_no));
            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });




    holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");

        Intent update_user = new Intent(activity,
            Update_User.class);
        update_user.putExtra("called", "update");
        update_user.putExtra("USER_ID", v.getTag().toString());
        activity.startActivity(update_user);


    }
    });
    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // show a message while loader is loading

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        adb.setTitle("Διαγραφή;");
        adb.setMessage("Είστε σίγουρος για τη διαγραφή; ");
        final int user_id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
        adb.setNegativeButton("Άκυρο", null);
        adb.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                int which) {
                // MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
                DatabaseHandler dBHandler = new DatabaseHandler(
                    activity.getApplicationContext());
                dBHandler.Delete_Contact(user_id);
                Promitheutis.this.onResume();

            }
            });
        adb.show();
    }

    });
    return row;

}



@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
      if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
}


private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

         if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Contact> filterList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                for (int i = 0; i < filterdata.size(); i++) {
                    if ( (filterdata.get(i).getEpitheto().toUpperCase() )
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        Contact cnt = new Contact(filterdata.get(i)
                                .getEpitheto() ,  filterdata.get(i)
                                .getPhoneNumber() ,  filterdata.get(i)
                                .getEidos());

                        filterList.add(cnt);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = filterdata.size();
                results.values = filterdata;
            }
            return results;
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        data = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

class UserHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView epitheto;
    TextView email;
    TextView number;
    TextView stathero;
    TextView eidos;
    TextView eponimia_user;
    TextView afm;
    TextView eidos2;
    TextView eidos3;
    Button edit;
    Button delete;
}

}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}





@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: dont use ArrayAdapter,  use SimpleCursorAdapter instead

Comment: can u help me with some code pls? because i am a bit lost in all of this :P

Comment: read this http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: I will read and will let you know if it helps me.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [This](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/). It Contain What you want and have source code also.

Comment: Thanks i followed the tutorial and changed my code and it worked..Thanks again!!